# PHP Round to previous multiple of 5 decimal

Tags: php, rounding

Expected function signature:

```
function roundToPreviousMultipleWithDecimal(float $number, int $x = 5): float;
```

- 8.4 => 8.0
- 8.6 => 8.5
- 8.9 => 8.5
- 9.0 => 9.0

Comment: What have you already try ?

Comment: 8.5, 9.0, 8.0 none of these are multiples of 5 ?I suspect you mean round down to nearest 0.5

Comment: Yep my bad, 0.5.

Comment: i had a question about : why did you put an , int $x = 5 in function signature ?

Comment: In case the round would be customizable, but totally optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an easy solution, floor the double number and divide by two... 2 cents ;)

```
<?php

function roundToPreviousMultipleWithDecimal(float $number){

        return $specificRound = floor($number * 2) / 2;
}

$a = 8.4;
$b = 8.6;
$c = 8.9;
$d = 9.0;

echo roundToPreviousMultipleWithDecimal($a) ."<br />";
echo roundToPreviousMultipleWithDecimal($b) ."<br />";
echo roundToPreviousMultipleWithDecimal($c) ."<br />";
echo roundToPreviousMultipleWithDecimal($d) ."<br />";
```